# Should I use backend for portfolio website?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, storage, backend

Hello Guys I am creating porfolio website for an Animation Studio.and they waana add some vidoes on their portfolio website.. I am using ReactJs for website. Do i need any kind of clousd-storage for storing videos,or i just put vidoes inside React project,Kindly help me..

Comment: you could put your videos in youtube and embed it into your `React` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting videos yourself is always tricky. Due to bandwidth limitations, it would buffer a lot and depending on the amount of traffic, the cost could go through the roof as well.

I have done a similar site previously using Gatsby and hosting the videos on Vimeo or Youtube.